# Is it possible for Octave to use harddrive to store workspace in runtime?

Tags: memory-management, octave, hard-drive

I want to work with large matrices (of order 8000x8000), and have only 4GB of RAM. Octave quickly takes almost all memory and computer freezes when I define a few such matrices (I checked it is due to RAM and not CPU usage). Is it possible to utilize the space in HDD to store these matrices in runtime?

Maybe the program will be slower, but then it would still work.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: A matrix of size 8000x8000, even if of double precision, is only about 500MB. Maybe you have many of them around and be more careful by removing matrix that you no longer need. Despite that, what you ask is possible and very common. Search for what is called a swap space (you need to increase the size of your swap partition).

Comment: @carandrug I have 4 gb of swap space, yet my system froze when I defined 12 such matrices.

Comment: 12 such matrices is more than 6GB, so yeah, more than what you have. But note, if you had run out of memory, then octave would have crashed. If it froze, it's still running, just very slowly. I guess it is running very slowly because it's using the disks to make up for the lack of memory so it's already doing what you asked. I suggest you come up with a redesign of your code, that does not require 12 copies of the matrix.